# The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context (Azure database)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Consider the next scenario:

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application for a very simple project. The database is hosted on Azure. I have a separated project to handle the database operations. Now I want to use the Identity Framework to manage the security and authorization. In the most articles I have read there is a common solution:

1. Go to the ApplicationDbContext class
2. Change the "DefaultConnection" string by my own connection string ("SurveysEntities" in my case).
3. Compile and enjoy.

But in my case I am having the following exception after trying to create a new user:

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the
>   current context

Considerations:

1. I have used the "database first" approach.
2. My database is hosted on Azure.
3. I have repplicated the database tables created on a local enviroment (localdb) but the problem persists

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fix this by creating a standard connection string that pointed to the database where the ASP.NET Identity tables are (in my case the same database), used that connection string in :base.

Comment: The identity tables are in the same database. I have replicated them from my local environment (localdb).